# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.callbackFunction is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx, react-component

I am trying to update a parent components state properties from a child component.  I am writing a small POC that will send a request to get some data, update the parents `state` properties each time I send the request, and have another child component render the parents `state` properties into a graph (using CanvasJS).  Anyway, I have followed a few tutorials and they seem to be showing the same thing.  But when I implement it, I get the `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.callbackFunction is not a function` error.  Here is my code:

**Parent**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import H2Request from "./myRequest";

class AllComponents extends Component {
  state = {
    items: this.props.value
  };

  callbackFunction = childData => {
    this.setState({ items: childData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyRequest dataFromParent={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AllComponents;
```

**Child**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../App.css";

class MyRequest extends Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8003").then(response => {
      this.props.callbackFunction(response.data);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button_container">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          Refresh
        </button>
        <h1>
          Items:
          {JSON.stringify(this.props.dataFromParent, null, 2)}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyRequest;
```

But when I click my `Refresh` button, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.callbackFunction is not a function
(anonymous function)
src/components/h2Request.jsx:10
   7 |   axios.get("http://localhost:8003").then(response => {
>  8 |     this.props.callbackFunction(response.data);
   9 | ^ });
  10 | };
```

I have tried adding a `.bind(this)` on to the end of the `callbackFunction` call, but same thing.

Comment: callbackFunction is not available inside the child Component because you are not passing it inside the child component. You need to pass it down as a prop and call it inside the onClick handler.

Comment: You are not passing it as props, check the answer :)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you to everyone.  I'm still quite new to React (in fact, front-end dev in general), but this seems quite obvious now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you AllComponent, you have defined the function but not included in the child component props

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import H2Request from "./myRequest";

class AllComponents extends Component {
  state = {
    items: this.props.value
  };

  callbackFunction = childData => {
    this.setState({ items: childData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyRequest dataFromParent={this.state.items} /> // see no callBackFunction in props
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AllComponents;
```

Change your parent component to, (add callbackFunction as props, so it can be accessed in the child component as `this.props.callbackFunction()`)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import H2Request from "./myRequest";

class AllComponents extends Component {
  state = {
    items: this.props.value
  };

  callbackFunction = childData => {
    this.setState({ items: childData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyRequest dataFromParent={this.state.items} callbackFunction={()=>this.callbackFunction()} /> // add callback as props in here
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AllComponents;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is simple, you didn't passed the prop to child.

```
 <MyRequest dataFromParent={this.state.items} callbackFunction={this.callbackFunction} />
```

So in the child it will be able to call `this.props.callbackFunction`

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a value for the callbak prop of your Requestcomponent like so

```
<MyRequest
    dataFromParent={this.state.items}
    callbackFunction={this.callbackFunction.bind()}
/>
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowcom-59821475-ze3sr)